# Loading a Client Certificate into a WebView control in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, webview, client-certificates

I am creating a C# windows application that consists of a webview that loads up a single website, https://www.mysite.com, that requires a client certificate for authentication.

In my application itself, I have a PKCS12 file that is used to authenticate to the site. However the issue I am facing is how to set up a WebView control to use it. I have figured out how to communicate to a webservice that requires cert authentication by using the following:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.mysite.com");
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(p12_data_bytes, "p12_pwd");
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
```

However, while this works, what I am trying to do is to have the WebView control handle the authentication, either through a callback or by loading the pkcs12 file into the control somehow.

Does anyone have any ideas how I would go about doing this?

Thanks,